# Template argument deduction of string literal

Tags: c++

Consider this simple function

```
template<typename T>
void func(const T& x) {std::cout<< typeid(T).name();}
```

now if I call function `func("ddd")` , what does T deduces to? . If there were no `const` in `func`'s parameter , `T` would be simply `char [4]` , Whats confusing me is addition of `const` ,  what does T deduces to ?

is it : `const char [4]` . If I change the parameter to `T const &x` (i.e change order of `const`) does deduction produces `T` to `char const [4]` ?

Can anyone explain argument deduction with string literals?

Comment: If you call `func()`, I guess you'll get a compile error as `func` wants one parameter.

Comment: FYI `const char [4]` and `char const [4]` are the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals are arrays of const characters.

A reference to string literal of 4 chars is of type `char const (&)[4]`.

`const char [4]` and `char const [4]` are same types!

`char const (&)[N]`, `const char [N]` and `char const [N]` all deduce to `char const [N]`

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void func1(T& x) {std::cout<< typeid(T).name()<<std::endl;}

template<typename T>
void func2(const T& x) {std::cout<< typeid(T).name()<<std::endl;}

template<typename T>
void func3(T const &x) {std::cout<< typeid(T).name()<<std::endl;}

int main()
{
    char c[4]= {'a','b','c','d'};
    const char c1[4]= {'a','b','c','d'};
    char const c2[4]= {'a','b','c','d'};

    func1("abcd"); //prints char const [4]
    func1(c); //prints char [4]
    func1(c1); //prints char const [4]
    func1(c2); //prints char const [4]

    func2("abcd"); //prints char const [4]
    func2(c); //prints char [4]
    func2(c1); //prints char const [4]
    func2(c2); //prints char const [4]

    func3("abcd"); //prints char const [4]
    func3(c); //prints char [4]
    func3(c1); //prints char const [4]
    func3(c2); //prints char const [4]

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "char const (&)[4], const char [4] and char const [4] are all same types!" -- One of those three is a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

> now if I call function func() , what does T deduces to?

If you call with a string literal, then `T` deduces to `char const[N]`.

> If there were no const in func's parameter , T would be simply char [4]

If you mean that if you declared the parameter as `T& x`, then no: `T` would still be deduced to `char const[N]` if you call with a string literal.

If you mean that you call `func` with a non-const array, then yes: `T` would be deduced non-const.

> If I change the parameter to T const &x

That changes nothing because `const T &` is just another way of writing `T const &`.

Answer (score 0):

`const` usually refers to whatever is *in front* of it:

`char const *` -- pointer to constant char

`char * const` -- constant pointer to char

`char const * const` -- constant pointer to constant char

`char Foo::bar() const` -- constant member function returning char

etc.

The *leading* `const` is an *exception* dating back to the early days of C:

`const char *` <=> `char const *`

So, changing the ordering in your template would not change the type at all (`T const &` <=> `const T &`).

If you want to be *consistent* about `const` placement, use the trailing type exclusively, because it's the only way you *can* place `const` consistently.